# Genymotion, “Unable to load VirtualBox engine.” on Yosemite. Virtualbox installed

Tags: android, macos, genymotion, osx-yosemite

I try to run genymotion but unsuccesful.

I already installed virtualbox but still the problem appears.

It says "Unable to load VirtualBox Engine"

[image]

Comment: unfortunately i cannot upload image as i dont have 10 rep. by the way i upload to dropbox. https://www.dropbox.com/s/xt0wairz7lup5hl/Screen%20Shot%202015-07-12%20at%206.48.58%20AM.png?dl=0

Comment: virtual box i installed is 5.0.0 but i am trying to install 4.3.29

Comment: Having the same issue. Downloaded and am able to run VirtualBox (5.0.0), but Genymotion doesn't seem to pick it up.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure you're running in to the same issue as me, but I resolved this by installing VirtualBox 4.3.28 (https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Download_Old_Builds_4_2). The new 5.0.0 and 4.3.30 versions don't seem to work with Genymotion 2.5.

Answer (score 0):

Try with

sudo /Library/StartupItems/VirtualBox/VirtualBox restart